# Attempting to install a phonegap plugin via command line

Tags: cordova, plugins, command-line

I have installed several plugin before into my Phonegap build. This one is giving me grief.

```
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode
```

I run these commands and everything install and builds correctly

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git
cordova build
```

But when I build to my Android device, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Class not found.
```

In the documentation here: `https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode` it has one step that I am not doing because I don't belive it applies to command line building.

It's this part here:

```
 PhoneGap Build

Add the following xml to your config.xml to always use the latest version of this plugin:

<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode" />
```

Any help would be awesome! App runs just fine without this plugin. Once it is added I get that error and other items in the app stop working. I mainly need this plugin for iOS to allow my application to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

The Phonegap Build line is only for configs when you are using the Phonegap Build service.

This is not the same as building on your computer with Cordova and Eclipse/Android SDK or Xcode.

I cannot help you with your problem save to tell you it's nothing to do with that Phonegap Build tag.

Comment: Hey I do appreciate what you have given. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on that. 
I've opened [an issue on the plugin repo](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/25) but no answer...
I'm guessing that if no answer is given, I'll ditch this solution and seek other options.